# Change store name via UpgradeData.php

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm new to Magento 2 and I was asked to write an update to change the name value of a store.

It looks like that :

```
store_id |code  |website_id |group_id |name       |sort_order |is_active |
---------|------|-----------|---------|-----------|-----------|----------|
0        |admin |0          |0        |Admin      |0          |1         |
1        |fr    |1          |1        |French     |0          |1         |
2        |en    |1          |1        |English    |0          |1         |
3        |de    |1          |1        |Deutsch    |0          |1         |
4        |en_us |2          |2        |USA        |0          |1         |
```

And I need the "USA" value to be "English US".

Here's what I came up with  :

```
<?php

namespace Dnd\Store\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

/**
 * Class UpgradeData
 *
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<=')) {
            if ($installer->getTableRow($installer->getTable('store'), 'store_id', 4)) {
                $installer->updateTableRow(
                    $installer->getTable('store'),
                    'store_id',
                    4,
                    'name',
                    'English US'
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't do anything when I `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Do you have any idea ?

**EDIT** : version comparaison in upgrade function + module.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Dnd_Store" setup_version="2.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Store"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

setup_module data : 2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your code and it works just fine. Therefore I assume that there is something wrong with the version of your module. Could you provide me with the content of etc/module.xml in module and version of data in setup_module table?

I think that something is wrong with the version, either with the value in compare function or in module.xml

Comment: Do you agree that I just need to run the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade
` command ?

Comment: Actually no. Current version of your module is 2.0.1 and version in module.xml is also 2.0.1. It means that upgrade data script will not be executed, there must be a difference between these two values. You must raise the version in module.xml to eg. 2.0.2 and change version in comparison function to 2.0.2.

Comment: Even with "<=" ? That's really a shitty problem I was facing... So much time lost...

Comment: Even with. Imagine a situation where setup upgrade is run for different purposes and some of upgrade scripts are same as your - they would run every time eventually overriding already changed data. For the same reason it is discouraged to use '<=', '<' should be use instead.

Comment: I know I shouldn't thank here but you deserve it : thank you